# S3 put policy for copying object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm quite new in S3. My use case is that we want to copy some objects from one bucket to another (I manage both of them) as described in [CopyObject - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html).

On the other hand we want to use Post Policies as described in [Creating a POST Policy - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html).

My question is - is it possible to do that, or the POST policies from above are only for POST request (copy is PUT request).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of how the policy you've tried and with any relevant error messages?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we are just starting with the project and I was hoping sb already had similar problem

Comment: Why are you wanting to use a POST? It would be easier to use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) to call the Copy command. What language are you using? Have you tried using an AWS SDK?

Comment: I'm using apex (Salesforce) so unfortunately no ask is awailable for it